# JNativeHook Keyboard listener isn't working with my Swing/GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm making some Mouse/Keyboard/Pixels classes that can simulate and read native input events. These are implementated as a wrappers around java.awt.Robot and [JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/). They're intended to be used as replacements for AutoHotKey or AutoIt on a Mac. I'm doing my testing on a Windows 7 64bit machine.

My problem is that I can't figure out why my keyboard listener for [JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) isn't working. I haven't got around to testing if the Mouse listeners work yet. It's possibly related to multi-threading issues with Swing and [JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/), but I haven't ruled out problems with the library or build version.

Most of my code is directly from the example page. JNativeHook spams the Logger and console with debug information for the mouse/keyboard but it doesn't call the listener. I'm using the latest jar from the download page as well as Eclipse and the latest jdk/jre unless something went horribly wrong with the installs.

**Test class**

The program displays a button and a colored panel. Pressing the button and then typing "1" should change the panel's color to be the same as the pixel under my mouse cursor.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JFrame implements NativeKeyListener, WindowListener {
    JPanel panel1 = null;
    JButton button1 = null;
    static final int PAD = 20;

    public Test() {
        // Disable console/log spam from JNativeHook
        /*
        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage()
                .getName());
        logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        */

        setTitle("Test");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(300, 270);

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel1.setSize(40, 40);
        panel1.setLocation(20, 20);
        panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1);

        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setText("Button1");
        button1.setSize(100, 20);
        button1.setLocation(20,
                panel1.getHeight() + panel1.getY() + PAD);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Keys.addKeyListener(new NativeKeyListener() {
                    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                        if(e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_1) {
                            Keys.removeKeyListener(this);
                            Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                            try {
                                panel1.setBackground(new Robot().getPixelColor(p.x, p.y));
                            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Listener Removed");
                        }
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                        System.out.println("Pressed");
                    }

                    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Released");
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    }

                    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Typed");
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    } 
                });
                System.out.println("Button1");
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        });
        this.getContentPane().add(button1);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(this);
        this.setVisible(true); // Display the window.
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        // Initialize native hook
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err
                    .println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        // Clean up the native hook
        GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
        System.runFinalization();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        /* Unimplemented */
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        /* Unimplemented */
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        /* Unimplemented */
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        /* Unimplemented */
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        /* Unimplemented */
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_SPACE) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "This will run on Swing's Event Dispatch Thread.");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        /* Unimplemented */
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        /* Unimplemented */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Keys class**

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.AWTKeyStroke;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class Keys {
    protected static Robot r = null;

    static {
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Keys() {
    } // STATIC CLASS

    public static void setRobot(Robot r) {
        Keys.r = r;
    }

    public static Robot getRobot(Robot r) {
        return r;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the delay between each key Press/Release.
     * 
     * @param ms
     *            Number of milliseconds to delay. Zero removes any delay.
     */
    public static void setDelay(int ms) {
        r.setAutoDelay(ms);
    }

    /**
     * @param keycode
     *            Key to send, for example KeyEvent.VK_0 for the 0 key.
     */
    public static void send(int keycode) {
        r.keyPress(keycode);
        r.keyRelease(keycode);
    }

    /**
     * @param keycode
     *            Key to send, for example KeyEvent.VK_0 for the 0 key.
     */
    public static void press(int keycode) {
        r.keyPress(keycode);
    }

    /**
     * @param keycode
     *            Key to send, for example KeyEvent.VK_0 for the 0 key.
     */
    public static void release(int keycode) {
        r.keyRelease(keycode);
    }

    public static void send(char c) {
        String str = "" + c;
        send(str);
    }

    /**
     * Doesn't support ALT, CTRL, NUMLOCK, or CAPSLOCK. Might not support every
     * key.
     * 
     * @param str
     *            The string to simulate typing.
     */
    public static void send(String str) {
        boolean shiftOn = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            int keycode = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(c).getKeyCode();
            boolean isLower = Character.isLowerCase(c);
            if (shiftOn) {
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    shiftOn = false;
                }
            } else if (!isLower) {
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                shiftOn = true;
            }
            r.keyPress(keycode);
            r.keyRelease(keycode);
        }
        if (shiftOn) {
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        }
    }

    public static void addKeyListener(NativeKeyListener listener) {
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(listener);
    }

    public static void removeKeyListener(NativeKeyListener listener) {
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().removeNativeKeyListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to add listeners unconditionally inside another listener. Listeners will build up (there's no check for duplicates).

Comment: Tested with JNH 1.1.4 and 1.2.0-beta2, both work with your (almost) unmodified code. I had to change all `VC_` constants to `VK_`. What version could you possibly be using that's not backwards compatible? (edit: haven't tested rc3, and I need to go now)

Comment: @mark I can't mark as "solved" until tomorrow or I could have saved you some time. Appreciate the effort, though.

Comment: @mark You're right. I need to make sure that if the user clicks the  button it will only register a listener once until it's removed.

Comment: @mark I also couldn't tell you why my version uses VC instead of VK. I know my constants for NativeKeyEvent are different than the KeyEvent, which is annoying. It would be nice if they followed the standard or had some translation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the jar build from RC3 to Beta2 and it works for Windows. Beta2 didn't work on Mac but I think RC 2 or 3 did.

Comment: There was a small but wide reaching bug in RC3.  Everything except a small exception bug should be fixed in RC4.